# Xml audio list player not working on the mobile and autoplay is not working

Tags: javascript, xml, jquery-mobile, avaudioplayer, jwplayer

I have been working on a multimedia website,, but i am stuck in a problem for the last three days.

I want to integrate an audio player in my website so that it can show the playlist in XML and also have an autoplay.

I have tried many free and paid audio player. In last i choose JW Player it has XML playlist integration but it is not working when mobile website is accessed by the user. and Autoplay is not working. Please solve my problem what can i change in JW player to solve these issues.

Answer (score 1):

First, forget about autoplay. This has been repeated so many times, it's getting tiresome:

***There is no autoplay possible on a mobile device.***

The mobile devices themselves disable this. There are very good reasons for doing this - expensive bandwidth, disruption in meetings, restaurants, etc. There is no way around this. There is no player on Earth that can bypass this.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I want my application to work like youtube. For eg: In youtube we got a list of videos. Then on click on a particular video from the list, that comes to the player and plays automatically. That is some what similar to what i am trying to implement. In my application, when i click on  a audio, it comes to the player but does'n play. Then again i have to click on it to play it. I want to save that second click on my application.

Comment: YouTube has an app. You should provide a link as well to your site in question to where the issue is happening.